# HtmlUnit - "Browser Not Supported" Error on website using JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, htmlunit

I would like to use HtmlUnit to login to website and click a link so that a file would be downloaded, however, the website, which uses JQuery, returns a "Browser Not Supported" Error. Is there a way that HtmlUnit can be set to look exactly like a normal browser to this website?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to do this with the following settings, but the error is still occurring:

```
    public void surf(Job job) {

    System.out.println("[Enter] surf");

    try {

        String applicationName = "Netscape";
        String applicationVersion = "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.41";
        int browserVersionNumeric = 51;

        BrowserVersion browser = new BrowserVersion(applicationName, applicationVersion, userAgent, browserVersionNumeric);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(browser);

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.europasports.com");

        System.out.println(page);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("[Exit] surf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_(web_browser)) was discontinued in March 2008, that's why you are getting the message. It no longer exists! If you are targeting Apple, i suggest you use Safari, but Google Chrome currently has [the largest browser usage share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)

Comment: The "Netscape" string isn't the problem here - all browsers except IE 1-10 use "Netscape" as their name in navigator.appName. I tried their code with "Microsoft Internet Explorer" and that didn't fix it.

Comment: the code for IE is (uppercase)  INTERNET_EXPLORER. Anyway you should use navigator.userAgent - its about the only one that detects the diff between IE and Edge